# MU-MIMO with spatially separated antennas

Tags: wireless, access-point

Assume a MU-MIMO capable wifi access point with two external antennas.  The antennas are placed in two different locations. It's not possible for a wifi signal to reach (via air) from one location to the other.

Given this setting: Should the access point be able to serve clients at both locations simultaneously? (E.g one client at one location, one client at the other)

Put differently: Do clients need to be able to receive from both antennas of that access point in order to establish a connection?

Comment: Antennas for MU-MIMO need to be in relative proximity - how is the beam shaping supposed to work otherwise?

Comment: @Zac67 .. do you have a source for this? If only one antenna carries the signal for a client then that forms a "beam" (localized signal), too, doesn't it?

Comment: No. (Virtual) beam forming implies the presence of an antenna array (2+). The beam is formed by multiple, spatially distinct, interfering signals. With a single antenna the antenna shape would need to be exactly as required - that can't be done ad-hoc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamforming